# browse server button missing laravel 5 elfinder ckeditor

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, elfinder

I am having an issue with the integration of ElFinder and CKEditor in my Laravel 5 project.

I use the CKEditor full package and I use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder for the Elfinder part.

However I am not getting any browse server button when I want to add an image.
Maybe this is related to an error I get in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined
```

Has anyone had a similar issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/elfinder/ckeditor';
```

in ckeditor/config.js. Also make sure you have registered the service in config/app.php